# Is there a way to produce a line on a raster, which direction is based on cell values?

Tags: raster, hydrology

I am looking at a raster layer where each cell has one of 8 values, indicating where flow from the cell is directed. Is there a way to select any given cell, and have a line drawn which will follow the direction of cells as it reaches them.
This can be thought about like a hydrology flow map essentially, using flow direction to draw a path along cells until we reach a pit or output cell. Is there any code out there which may help? I'm sure this must have been done before somewhere.

Comment: What software are you using? Are you interested in writing/customizing code or a tool that already works as you describe?

Comment: Have been looking at Arc, GRASS, python. There is no preference of what software is used, as long as it can get the job done. It would be nice to write/customize the code, or have something open-source.

Comment: Arc Hydro tools has some useful utilities https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5df49d4dfc7c4bdea7f06eca37a17389 (page 137 of the tutorial http://downloads.esri.com/archydro/archydro/tutorial/doc/arc%20hydro%20tools%202.0%20-%20tutorial.pdf) the good news is it's free to download.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want. Very appreciated :) Case closed, you're a legend!